# What is a cross-browser shim to `console.clear`?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, console

`console.clear` can't be reliably used as it is not implemented in many browsers. There are different ways to access this function in different browsers. What is a proper shim that will take care of all cases, falling back to printing `\n`s in case of unavailability?

Comment: `console` is for debugging/development and is non-standardized (even `console.log` varies greatly). As a developer, I'd rather not "clear", except when I choose it so manually.

Comment: @zerkms no, because one would have to research the specific methods for a huge set of browsers.

Comment: @user2864740 clearing the console is very useful for some applications where you want to visualize data that is updated in real-time (ie, keeping track of the mouse position - it is difficult to follow thousands of messages per second, so console.clear allows it to stay in the same line).

Comment: `if (!'clear' in console) console.clear = function() {..`

Comment: @Viclib That's not a good use of the console, IMOHO. There are better ways (including "log emulators") for collecting/visualizing such data.

Comment: @user2864740 well you could obviously just place an element but sometimes you don't want to affect the site space or just are in a hurry to properly place it. And the need for a shim comes from having to have it to run in other developer's who are working with you browsers.